# Matching a capturing group or failng the match if missing in Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to grab a digit (`5`) followed by a possible `-` or  (space) proceeding a sequence of 3 digits, followed finally by a single digit. If the first group doesn't match at all, then only return the other sequences of digits.

```
^(5\-? ?)?(\d{3})(\d)$
```

This looks right to me and doesn't throw any errors, but it's giving the `5` back:

```
"5489" -> ()("548")("9")
```

Where I would actually not want this expression to return a match for this pattern.

So a quick search brought me to possessive expressions and a lot of articles about your ex. From what I'm reading, this looks like it should work:

```
^(5\-? ?)?+(\d{3})(\d)$
```

But Javascript does **not** like that as a regular expression.

Is there a way to do a greedy possessive capture group in Javascript, or simulate it in this situation?

Comment: No possessive quant's in JS `?+`

Comment: @sin if you have an authoritative reference for that please post it as an answer, I will absolutely accept that. Workarounds also appreciated if they exist :)

Comment: If you have a look at the [ECMAScript 5](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.1) docs, you will see there is no support for possessive quantifiers.

Comment: If it's just _not 5_ then this `^(5\-? ?)?((?!5)\d{3})(\d)$`

Comment: Try [`^(?!5\d{3}$)(5\-? ?)?(\d{3})(\d)$`](https://regex101.com/r/8aZ7yd/1). It will fail a match at once if the string starts with `5` and then has 3 digits.

Comment: Come on guys, these are great ideas you have! Don't be afraid to post answers. I'll even update the question to accommodate.

Comment: @RandyHall - There is no reason to force anything. You've got a _fixed_ amount of digits to match at the end, plus you're using anchors `^$`. The conclusion is that if you have 4 digits only they will be matched at the end because its a tenent of the regex design. If you don't want to match 4 digits starting with a `5`, then it's an extra assertion, but has nothing to do with forcing a capture of the first group. I'm just stating this as a comment because it's an X/Y problem, and I don't like to post for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the [ECMAScript 5](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.1) docs, you will see there is no support for possessive quantifiers.

You may use

```
^(?!5\d{3}$)(5-? ?)?(\d{3})(\d)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8aZ7yd/3). The `(?!5\d{3}$)` *negative lookahead* will fail a match at once if the string starts with `5` and then has 3 digits.

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of string
- `(?!5\d{3}$)` -  there cannot be `5` and then 3 digits and the end of string immediately to the right of the current location
- `(5-? ?)?` - an optional sequence of `5`, then an optional `-` and then an optional space
- `(\d{3})` - 3 digits
- `(\d)` - one digit
- `$`  - end of string.

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate possessive quantifier functionality by taking advantage of lookaround qualities:

```
^(?=(...))\1
```

Regex:

```
^(?=((5\-? ?)?))\1(\d{3})(\d)$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/RLqOAT/1)

Comment: +1 I think this is the better answer. One, that it simulates possessive, two, that it won't match `5890` but will match `55890`.